# How to update an element on a Live page once a background task has been finished?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I have a table on a LV page. Each row has a button which is supposed to refresh data in a row. To refresh it, it has to send at least one request to an external API which may take a few seconds or as well as a few minutes. Data received from an external API gets saved into a DB.

I could make a user wait, but it'll be better to create a background task and return a response immediately which says something like "being updated"

Once a response has been received, how will I notify a live page about this, to then make it refresh its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you handled the click event, triggered a background job, and updated the state of the socket with a kind of "updating..." message.

now the background job finished successfully and should notify the original liveview process. it needs to send a message to this liveview. [Phoenix.PubSub](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html) well be used for this at best.

the liveview should [subscribe](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html#subscribe/3) to a topic, typically inside `mount()`, the background job will be the publisher, it will [broadcast](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html#broadcast/4) a message -typically a tuple holding the updated record after being fetched- to all subscribers, the liveview process is internally a gen_server where a `handle_info` callback can be implemented, in your [`handle_info/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#c:handle_info/2) you can pattern match on that message and update you socket state accordingly.